# Create a Gtk.TreeView from a flat file list GTK C#

Tags: c#, treeview, monodevelop, gtk#

I am wondering if any one could help me I am just learning Gtk and c# and I am finding it hard to find an example which shows how to create a TreeView from a flat list of files.

```
            var paths = new List<string>
                    {
                        @"C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\MUI\040C",
                        @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727",
                        @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MUI",
                        @"C:\WINDOWS\addins",
                        @"C:\WINDOWS\addins\file1.f",
                        @"C:\WINDOWS\addins\file2.f",
                        @"C:\WINDOWS\addins\file3.f",
                        @"C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch",
                        @"C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\MUI",
                        @"C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\hello.JPG",
                        @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MUI\0409"
                    };
```

Then I am then trying to put them into a hierarchical form and put them into a tree, I am unsure how to create tree from the flat paths.

```
    private static void FillTree(IEnumerable<string> paths)
    {
        FileTreeView = new Gtk.TreeView();
        Add(FileTreeView);

        Gtk.TreeViewColumn Column = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();

        string subPathA;
        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            subPathAgg = string.Empty;
            var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            builder.Append(subPathAgg);
            foreach (string subPath in path.Split(@"\"))
            {
                builder.Append(subPath + @"\");

                Console.WriteLine(subPath + @"\");
            }
            subPathAgg = builder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TreeView** is a powerful widget, in my opinion a too powerful mixing.
I wrote a [*GtkUtil* module](https://github.com/Baltasarq/GtkUtil) that contains the **GtkTableTextView** class, which makes it easier to user the **TreeView**.

With this class, you will be able to create the table as follows:

```
var tvTable = new Gtk.TreeView();
this.Add( tvTable );

var Headers = new string[] { "#", "Path" };
var ttTable = new GtkUtil.TableTextView( this.tvTable, Headers.Count, Headers.Count );
ttTable.Headers = Headers;

foreach(string path in paths) {
    ttTable.AppendRow();
    ttTable.Set( i, 1, path );
}

this.ShowAll();
```

If you still prefer to do it without a library, then you should follow [the standard tutorial about treeview](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/widgets/treeview-tutorial/).

```
var tree = new Gtk.TreeView ();
this.Add( tree );

// Create a column for the file path
Gtk.TreeViewColumn pathColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn ();
pathColumn.Title = "Path";
tree.appendColumn( pathColumn );

// Create an appropriate model
var pathListStore = new Gtk.ListStore( typeof( string ) );
tree.Model = pathListStore;

// Add the data
foreach(string path in paths) {
    tree.AppendValues( path );
}

this.ShowAll();
```

Hope this helps.